# What is this small tree found growing from a wall?

Tags: identification, trees

I've found this plant growing in a crack in the wall. I then put it in a pot and is growing fast.
Can anyone help me identify it, I live in Buenos Aires, Argentina.

[image]

This is how it looks now (2016-2-10):

[image]

Comment: Looks Mulberryish: https://www.google.com/search?q=Mulberry&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjto_bAwtzJAhVE9R4KHT-jC4sQ_AUIBygB&biw=1306&bih=716 there's a lot of leaf diversity on those, so you may have to wait a few years until it fruits to be sure.

Comment: Yeah I was going to say mulberry. I had hundreds of them in Iowa. Do any of the leaves look glove-ish.

Comment: Do you have any Hibiscus near you? Might be a better bet for your region. Compare to, e.g., [H. syriacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibiscus_syriacus).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say I believe that is a [*Morus alba*](http://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=527), white mulberry, which is becoming quite invasive in Argentina (and pretty much everywhere else it's been introduced).

It's hard to tell at this stage, but that's my best guess. If you want to let it grow out a bit, that might make an absolute identification apparent.

Comment: In the Midwest of USA it would more likely be red mulberry. Not as tasty as black mulberry but most berries are tasty. White mulberry isn't good for food, it's really only good for raising silkworm.

Comment: @Escoce The OP lives in Argentina